# Validation to reject input if it consists of ALL numbers, contains space/s, and period/s (.)

Tags: validation, input, powershell-3.0

In PowerSell, how can I include the necessary code, to the code below, that would reject any input that consists entirely of numbers/digits, but would accept alpha/alphanumeric values with or without hyphens, but NOT spaces or periods (.)?

```
DO {
$NewID = Read-Host -Prompt " NEW ID NAME of object (8-15 chars)   "
} UNTIL ($NewID.Length -gt 7 -and $NewName.Length -lt 16)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if($foo -notmatch '^\d+$' -and $foo -match '^\w[\w-]*$') { ...ok } else { ...bad }
```

Example:

```
@( "123", "123 T", "123T", "123-T-456", "123 T 456" ) | 
foreach-object { 
    if( $_ -notmatch '^\d+$' -and $_ -match '^\w[\w-]*$') { "'$_' passed" } 
    else { "'$_' failed" } 
}
```

Results:

```
'123' failed
'123 T' failed
'123T' passed
'123-T-456' passed
'123 T 456' failed
```

Comment: worked great! the code is simple and short enough to meet the conditions. Can I get the meaning of the parameters used for the conditions used: `'^\d+$'` and `'^\w[\w-]*$'`, as in, how are those parameters interpreted by PowerShell, which character/s define which condition/s? Thanks.